# unable to write the output into a file in perl

Tags: perl, file, url-rewriting

I want to write the result of my code into a file , but it's not written into my file. My code is working and it's about removing duplicate line, but when i wanted to write the output into a file, the file is empty. This is my code:

```
 use strict;
    use warnings;

    open(DATA,"/root/Desktop/SIEMENS/printtokens/outputs/common_distinct/MR1/thiscommon.txt");
    open FILE2, ">/root/Desktop/SIEMENS/printtokens/outputs/common_distinct/MR1/common_element.txt" or die $!;

    my %lines;
    #open DATA, $ARGV[0] or die "Couldn't open $ARGV[0]: $!\n";
    while (<DATA>) {
    print if not $lines{$_}++;
    print FILE2 if not $lines{$_}++;

    }

    close DATA;
    close FILE2;
```

Answer (score 1):

This works as expected

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open(my $in, '<', './in.txt');
open(my $out, '>', './out.txt');

my %lines;
while (<$in>) {
    print $out $_ unless $lines{$_}++;
}

close $in;
close $out;
```

Note the usage of the 3-argument open, lexical filehandles and the `autodie` pragma.

Me as a fan of the usage of [CPAN](http://metacpan.org) modules, would write the same as:

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use Path::Tiny;
use List::Util qw(uniq);

my $out_file = './out.txt';
my $in_file = './in.txt';
path($out_file)->spew( uniq path($in_file)->lines );
```

Comment: Anyway, i've got another way and it works. Thanks, btw.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem probably is that `$lines{$_}++` changes the value of `$lines{$_}` so the second will never evaluate to false. You could probably fix your problem just by removing `++` on the first occurence. But for readability I would recommend wrapping both output lines with one if statement, avoid using `$_` and remembering to close the files, so something like:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %lines;

open(my $in, '<', './in.txt');
open(my $out, '>', './out.txt');

while (my $line = <$in>) {
    unless ($lines{$line}++) {
        print STDOUT $line;
        print {$out} $line
    }
}

close($in);
close($out);
```

As you can see, I also prefer lexical filehandles and 3-argument open.

Comment: You forgot to declare `$line`, your code won't compile. (just change your while condition to `(my $line = <$in>)` )

Comment: That started out just being the while loop, and then I decided I should also recommend 3-argument open and closing the files, and then that I might just as well provide complete code - and then I still forgot that :-( - But, thanks @Dada

Comment: No, actually this code is works for me. Anyway, i've fix my code with another way. Thanks for your help, btw.

Comment: *"avoid using `$_`"* That is a style choice. Most experienced Perl programmers are perfectly happy with using the "pronoun variable" `$_` and it can make code much clearer and more readable.

Comment: *"remembering to close the files"* Perl will close all open file handles at the end of a run (or when a lexical file handle is destroyed at the end of a block) and is rarely necessary unless you want to be sure that an output file closed successfully, and you don't test the success of your `close` calls so they're pointless. Any code-breaking errors on input file handles will have happened before the end of the file.

Comment: Yes, they don't matter here, but I believe it's better to always do so, to lower the risk of forgetting it somewhere that it does matter.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you want in common_element.txt, but I think the logic in the read loop is wrong. No need to increase the $lines twice, and only output if there is a match from existing data?

Try:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(DATA,"thiscommon.txt");
open (FILE2, '>common_element.txt') or die $!;

my %lines;
while (<DATA>) {
  print FILE2 if $lines{$_};
  print if not $lines{$_}++;
}

close DATA;
close FILE2;
```

Only with your paths, obviously.

Comment: I have tried your suggest before, but it didn't work. And i fix it, Finally, i got another way. Thanks you for your response anyway.